# Query backlink on two fields with same type

Tags: realm

I have a relationship between Product and its units describe in schema as below:

```js
public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    name: Product.schemaName,
    primaryKey: 'sku',
    properties: {
      name: {type: 'string'},
      baseUnit: {type: SoldableUnit.schemaName},
      derivedUnits: {type: 'list', objectType: SoldableUnit.schemaName},
     
    },
  };
public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    name: SoldableUnit.schemaName,
    embedded: true,
    properties: {
      unitName: {type: 'string'},
      sellingPrice: {type: 'double'},
      weight: {type: 'float'},
      barcode: {type: 'string', optional: true, indexed:true},
    },
  };
```

The idea is a `product` can have one `baseUnit` and many `derivedUnits`, and both `baseUnit` and `derivedUnit`s are `SoldableUnit` with the same schema. I want to query `product` by `barcode`. Here I have to return the product, providing a barcode which maybe equals to barcode of baseUnit or derived units. After some research, I find out that I can use backlink to return inverse relationship. The problem here is SoldableUnit occurs both in baseUnit and derivedUnits and I dont know how to achieve this goals? And whether the schema design of Product is appropriate?

Comment: Please tag the question with your development language. Also, it appears SoldableUnit is an embedded object? If so, there isn't a relationship in the traditional sense so there wouldn't be a forward/inverse (backlink). Embedded objects are more akin being a property of the parent object than being a separate object. Take a look a the docs [Query Embedded Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/data-types/embedded-objects/#query-a-collection-on-embedded-object-properties). When you query for the embedded objects barcode, the parent object will be returned.

Comment: Yes, thank @Jay . I've asked realm author and they reply exactly the same as you say. Yeah, no need to use backlink here